# Cant look up or down

Tags: garrys-mod

In Garry's Mod, I can't look up or down and I only can look side to side. The last thing I did in my Garry's Mod was unbindall and I restored all controls to default which didn't work. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try deleting your config.cfg in the garrysmod folder

Answer (score 0):

You must have messed something up when restoring to defaults. Check the control settings and look for the Y axis. Changing that to the correct setting should work.

Comment: @aytimothy Do you have proof to support this?